# Add iOS Developer Account From Command Line

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, build-automation

I am trying to automate the build process a little bit and I have been able to automate a build for developer accounts already added to XCode.

I have searched quite a bit, but have not been able to find my answer. I found where the login credentials are stored in the keychain but adding a new entry to the keychain does not make the account show up in XCode.

Does anyone know how to add another account to the XCode Account preferences through command line or other scripting methods?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alrighty, so I figured out the issue. It wasn't that it needed to have the account added it was that even though I was specifying the 'PROFILE_PATH' when using xcodebuild it was still unable to use the provisioning profile I had specified. Instead what I ended up doing was simply copying the .mobileprovision file to the ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/ folder. All seems to work great now.

The reason I thought it needed the account was because if I logged in with the account in XCode it would all of a sudden work. I didn't realize that XCode automatically downloads all provisioning profiles from your account upon addition of the account and places them in the previously mentioned folder.